# delete all emails from Outlook 2010 inbox retaining only the last 3 months

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have 9000 emails in my account. How do you delete all emails from Outlook 2010 inbox retaining only the last 3 months.

Comment: Is it feasible to do it manually? Select all (ctrl+a), deselect the ones from the last 3 months, delete the remaining ones.

Comment: @MWijnand: Sorry no its not hence my question. :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [Outlook search filters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da).

Using a filter such as:

`received:=<29/10/2015`

will return all emails received on that date and before. You can then simply delete all returned results.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (if you want less destructive) is to simply use the Archiving (and auto archiving) tool to run as often as you like all emails older than the amount you want (3 months). It will then push these emails to another account.